# MySQL function with REPLACE throwing syntax error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I created a function which works in my database, but the CREATE code of this function generated by the IDE that I'm using([HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)) is throwing an error:

> Erro SQL (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 10

The generated code is the following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CONVERTE_VALOR`(`VALOR` VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS decimal(10,0)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Converte valor VARCHAR em DECIMAL para comparação'
BEGIN

    RETURN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(VALOR, '.', ''), ',', '.') AS UNSIGNED); /* Line 10 */

END
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `CONVERTE_VALOR`(`VALOR` VARCHAR(255))
    RETURNS decimal(10,0)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    NO SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT 'Converte valor VARCHAR em DECIMAL para comparação'
-- BEGIN
    RETURN CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(VALOR, '.', ''), ',', '.') AS UNSIGNED); /* Line 10 */
-- END
```